# How to boot to USB using grub

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8, boot, windows-8.1, grub2

My computer currently boots to grub2 at the moment.

I have an Ubuntu iso installation on my USB.

How can I make grub boot to my USB?

The way I'm used to doing it is like so: When on Windows 8.1 hold SHIFT while clicking the restart button and clicking "Choose another device" on the windows blue screen). However this does not seem to work.

Comment: Can you boot into the BIOS?  Usually the BIOS has options to select boot devices and boot order.

Comment: Wasn't able to unfortunately